# Reading each row into an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Im a bit stuck, I am able to read each row into an array but it is an associative array but I don't want that, i want a normal array `( array = ['2', '3', '4'] )`

also, my table only has 1 column, so it should be easier

here is my code.

`var_dump` gives me :

```
 array(3) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(44)      
 "0Av5k2xcMXwlmdEV6NXRZZnJXS2s4T3pSNzViREN6dHc" } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(44) 
 "0Av5k2xcMXwlmdDhTV2NxbXpqTmFyTUNxS0VkalZTSnc" } [2]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(44)   
 "0Av5k2xcMXwlmdDdhdVpMenBTZTltY2VwSXE0NnNmWWc" } }
```

which tells me it is an assosiative array?

```
 $fileList = getLiveList();
    var_dump($fileList);

function getLiveList(){
    $query = "SELECT id FROM livelist";
    $result = mysql_query($query); // This line executes the MySQL query that you typed above

    $array = []; // make a new array to hold all your data

    $index = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) // loop to give you the data in an associative array so you can use it however.
    {
         $array[$index] = $row;
         $index++;
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Comment: you don't need $index in your while loop: you can juste use $array[] = $row[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$fileList = getLiveList();
var_dump($fileList);

function getLiveList(){
    $query = "SELECT id FROM livelist";
    $result = mysql_query($query); // This line executes the MySQL query that you typed above

    $array = []; // make a new array to hold all your data

   while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) // loop to give you the data in an associative array so you can use it however.
   {
       $array[] = $row[0];
   }
   return $array;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just take `id` (first element) from row,

```
$array = []; // make a new array to hold all your data
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) // loop to give you the data in an associative array so you can use it however.
{
     $array[] = $row[0];
}
return $array;
```

**Note:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query return both indexed and associate arrays

use mysql_fetch_array or mysql_fetch_assoc based on your needs.

oh, and you should use mysqli functions instead :-)